# where can i declare class obj

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

i have windows form app
2 text box1,2
2 button1,2
i have class person {have get, set (string ,int)}
and i want to declare
person p;
to see it in both two push button1,2

my problem is i declare
person p; inside buttons when buttons end
p.~person();is called
so i cant save value

and when i call p.get i get initial value

code

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {person p;
      //string str;
  stringstr(constchar*)System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox1->Text).ToPointer();
             p.set( str,int ::Parse(textBox2->Text));


private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {person p;
          string str;
         int ag;
         p.get(str,ag);
```

i declare class as

```
 class person
{
public:
    person();// create initial value
    ~person();//descon
    void set(string z,int a);//set value
    void get(string &z,int &a);//get value
private:

    string name;
    int age ;

};

------------------------------------------------------------
person cpp
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "person.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

person::person()
{name="null";
 age=-1;

}
person::~person()
{
}

void person::set(string z, int a)
{name=z;
age= a;
}
void person::get(string &z, int &a)
{z =name;
a=age;
}
```

can i upload all solution or not?

Comment: If you indent your code four spaces, it will be auto-formatted for you.  You might consider reformatting your code so that it is easier to read.

Comment: And please don't put code on the same line as the opening bracket. It makes it hard to read.

Comment: This code is VERY weird.  `string` in C++/CLI is not a .NET string.  Since you have used `using namespace std;` you have gotten a native string in your managed code.  This is fine if you want to reuse existing native code, but I don't see any sign of that here.  Why not make `person` a `ref class` and use `System::String^` instead of `std::string`?  It will let you get rid of the ugly InteropServices function call.

Comment: With a managed type you will also be able to store it inside your form so it retains its value, you can do that with native classes as well but only by pointer, the native class can't be directly placed inside a managed type.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make p a member of the form object itself. That way it will be accessible to all the event handlers.

Just take `person p;` out of your event handler and put it in your form. In C# you would just put it above the first event handler--I'm not certain that's what you do in C++/CLI, but it's worth a shot.

```
person p;

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    ...
    // Use p here
    p.set( str,int ::Parse(textBox2->Text));
}


private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    ...
    // It's still the same p here
    p.get(str,ag);
}
```

Comment: Managed types can't have native types as data members, however you can have a pointer to a native object.  So it becomes `person* p;`, `p->set`, and `p` has to be allocated in the constructor and freed in the destructor and finalizer.